# Compare only a subset of the fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

According to the API doc of MongoDB, `$addToSet` is describe as such:

> If the value is a document, MongoDB determines that the document is a
>   duplicate if an existing document in the array matches the to-be-added
>   document exactly; i.e. the existing document has the exact same fields
>   and values and the fields are in the same order. As such, field order
>   matters and you cannot specify that MongoDB compare only a subset of
>   the fields in the document to determine whether the document is a
>   duplicate of an existing array element.

---

So other than `$addToSet`, what is the best way to insert new document into an array only when there is no duplicate data (compare the duplication on specific fields). Let's create an example.

```js
[{
    "Name"  : "Python",
    "Month" : new Date("2020-01-01"),
    "Sales":[
                {"date": new Date("2020-01-01"), "volume":1, product: ["a"]},
                {"date": new Date("2020-01-02"), "volume":2, product: ["a"]},
                {"date": new Date("2020-01-03"), "volume":3, product: ["a","b"]},
                {"date": new Date("2020-01-04"), "volume":4, product: ["a"]},
                {"date": new Date("2020-01-05"), "volume":5, product: ["a","b"]},
             ]
}]
```

I would like to insert new embedding document**s** into the sales array field of the above example documents.

edit: the sub-document use date as the index key

```js
[{"date": new Date("2020-01-05"), "volume":8, product: ["a","b","d"]} // Date already exist
{"date": new Date("2020-01-06"), "volume":6, product: ["a","b","c"]}] // new data
```

Three questions:

1. For data already exist in the database, I would like to update it with the new data.
2. How to perform in batch, instead of insert it one by one. (i.e. insert an array perform checking and update)
3. Insert only when no duplicate

Comment: Still this question is unclear !! `data already exist` what do you mean by that ? In case of `new Date("2020-01-05")` so date already exists then what would you like to do ?

Comment: the new data use "Date" as the key to indicate existence. Two scenario would like to explore. First, replace the sub-document when the same "date" exist. Second, ignore the upsert when the same "date" exist

Comment: So what is the key to search the docs, Is it python ?

Comment: it is in python, i would like to update one array field of a document. The array contains sub-documents and the key of this sub-documents is "Date" in python

Comment: If you are running MongoDB 4.2 You could use `$set`, `$cond`, `$size` and `$filter` inside a pipeline in the [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-parameter) expression